# Outlook API time difference in Calendar

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I have a problem with the use of the Outlook API specially with the Calendar API.

I send dates with a UTC format and when they are added in the Calendar, I have a difference with the send date.

I'm in France so the original date is in UTC+2. I convert in UTC and make my request with this configuration :

```
var options = {
            url: "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendars/" + workspace.calendarId + "/events?$Select=Id",
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "authorization": "Bearer " + host.outlookCalAccessToken,
                "accept" : "application/json",
                "ContentType" : "application/json"
            },
            json:{
                "Subject" : event.summary,
                "Body" : {
                    "ContentType" : "Text",
                    "Content" : event.description
                },
                "Start" : {
                    "DateTime":start,
                    "TimeZone" : "OriginStartTimeZone"
                },
                "End" : {
                    "DateTime":end,
                    "TimeZone" : "OriginStartTimeZone"

                },
                "Attendees" : [
                    {
                        "EmailAddress" : {
                            "Name" : nomad.firstname,
                            "Address" : nomad.email
                        },
                        "Type" : "Required"
                    }
                ]

            },
            "Content-Type" : "application/json"
        };
```

I have the same problem if the TimeZone is "OriginStartTimeZone" or "UTC".

For example, my local date is `2017-10-19T17:00:00.000`
It is converted to the UTC `2017-10-19T15:00:00.000Z`
And in the calendar the event date is `2017-10-19T08:00:00.000`

What have I missed with this API ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`OriginStartTimeZone` isn't a valid value for `TimeZone`. If you set `TimeZone` to `UTC` you should get the expected results. I just tested it here with this payload:

```
{
    "Subject" : "test",
    "Body" : {
        "ContentType" : "Text",
        "Content" : "hello"
    },
    "Start" : {
        "DateTime": "2017-10-19T15:00:00.000Z",
        "TimeZone" : "UTC"
    },
    "End" : {
        "DateTime": "2017-10-19T16:00:00.000Z",
        "TimeZone" : "UTC"
    }
}
```

Both in the response to my POST and subsequent GET requests for the event, I get back:

```
"Start": {
    "DateTime": "2017-10-19T15:00:00.0000000",
    "TimeZone": "UTC"
},
"End": {
    "DateTime": "2017-10-19T16:00:00.0000000",
    "TimeZone": "UTC"
},
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want your event **start** date to be 2017-10-19 at 10:30 local time, your start object should look like this:

```
Start:{DateTime: "2017-10-19T10:30:00+02:00", TimeZone: "UTC"}
```

Is this what your start object look like? If it does, then the event time should be shown correctly in the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the timezone to UTC, the problem still occured. I found what it doesn't work. In the webmail, the timezone was set to UTC-8 although I filled the right timezone when I registered...
Thanks for your answers !